# Python script switching between matplotlib inline and QT backend

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, backend

I would like to be able to switch between displaying matplotlib graphs inline or using QT backend in a script file based on a variable called inlinemode such as the code fragment below

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
inlinemode = False
if inlinemode:   
    print "plot will be inline..."
else:
    print "plot will be qt..."
    plt.switch_backend('qt4agg')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10))
```

My IPython console starts in inline mode by default, and executing the code fragment above still produces an inline graph instead of a qt window. If it was possible to send the IPython magic %matplotlib inline -or- %matplotlib qt in the if block, this would accomplish this task. However, from what I have been able to gather, it is not possible to send these magic's from a script file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

(FYI: I am running from Spyder in Anaconda Python 2.7 on Windows 10)

Comment: use the `%matplotlib qt` magic

Comment: The magic works if I execute the script from the IPython console using %run foo.py.  However, if I use the run button from Spyder, it sends runfile('foo.py') to IPython console. In that case, it comes up with a syntax error on the %matplotlib qt statement.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible using the following block, which will allow the script to be run in IPython using `%run` or directly through standard python.

```
try:
    import IPython
    shell = IPython.get_ipython()
    shell.enable_matplotlib(gui='inline')
except:
    pass
```

This is what the magic `%matplotlib inline` is actually doing under the hood.  You can change the keyword argument to be `gui='qt'` to select a different backend.